# Column querying from connection not working for Postgresql but not for Hsql in Java

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hsqldb

I am encountering weird behavior where my integration tests for my JPA Configuration are failing for postgresql but passing for hsql. There are no code changes to the test and assertion method.

I have verified that the table and columns are being added appropriately to the database. Verification for table existence passes ok, but only the column check fails unexpectedly.

What is the root cause of this? Is there a workaround or fix for this issue?

Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=PersistenceConfig.class)
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=true)
public class UserMappingIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    EntityManager manager;

    @Test
    public void thatUserMappingWorks() {
        assertTableExists(manager, "USER_TABLE");
        assertTableHasColumn(manager, "USER_TABLE", "NAME");
    }
}
```

Assertion method:

```
public static void assertTableHasColumn(EntityManager manager,
        final String tableName, final String columnName) {
    SessionImpl session = (SessionImpl) manager.unwrap(Session.class);

    final ResultCollector rc = new ResultCollector();

    session.doWork(connection -> {
        ResultSet columns = connection.getMetaData().getColumns(null, null,
                tableName.toUpperCase(), null);
        while (columns.next()) {
            if (columns.getString(4).toUpperCase()
                    .equals(columnName.toUpperCase())) {
                rc.found = true;
            }
        }
    });

    if (!rc.found) {
        fail("Column [" + columnName + "] not found on table : "
                + tableName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, what does PostgreSQL return from `getMetaData().getColumns()`?

Comment: Oh, I know what's going on. PgJDBC returns quoted identifiers. It's a bug, IMO. See https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/117

Comment: After checking further today, I found out that table is not found because the search string is in upper case (despite being declared all caps via JPA in object)